# event propagation in three.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, three.js

I have a scene with several objects. I use an orthographic camera controller. When I have a selected object, I want to rotate it with the mouse using shiftKey + but 1 (rotation around its own center) and translate it in the scene using shiftKey + but 3.

When setting up my mouse events handlers, I tried to stop the camera controls to fire, but it still does as soon as button is up.

Can someone show me where I'm wrong ?

```
$(canva).mousedown(function (e) {
if (selObject && e.shiftKey) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation()
    e.cancelBubble=true;
    e.returnValue=false;

    controls.enabled = false

    mDown = e.which
    clientX = e.clientX
    clientY = e.clientY

    return false
}
});

$(canva).mousemove(function (e) {
if (! selObject || ! mDown) {
    return true
}

e.stopPropagation()
e.preventDefault();
e.cancelBubble=true;
e.returnValue=false;

dX = e.clientX - clientX
dY = e.clientY - clientY

if (mDown == 1) {
    dX /= 100
    dY /= 100

    selObject.rotation.x += dX
    selObject.rotation.y += dY
} else if (mDown == 3) {
    dX /= 2
    dY /= 2

    var pos = mouse2world(e)
    selObject.position = pos
}
clientX = e.clientX
clientY = e.clientY

return false
});

$(canva).mouseup(function (e) {
if (mDown) {
    mDown = 0

    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation()
    e.cancelBubble=true;
    e.returnValue=false;

    controls.enabled = true

    return false
}
});
```

Comment: You are probably looking for `event.stopImmediatePropagation()`.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
event.stopImmediatePropagation();
```

instead of

```
event.stopPropagation();
```

Source: MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopImmediatePropagation

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't work. I set the body of mouseupfunction to nothing to be sure it's not interferring with events. Something is propagated to the camera controls...

Comment: You would need to apply the stopping of propagation in your mouseup event as well (empty body does exactly nothing and changes exactly nothing).

Comment: Ooops ! Sorry ! I should have said that empty means nothing apart the stopImmediatePropagetion() and preventFefault() and return false !! With thiese three lines, events are still propagated...

Comment: @luckyluc67 Actually, `mouseup` does not emit an event (its `event` is empty) so it shouldn't do anything directly... Are you using threejs default controls somwhere? Are they attached to the renderer or the document element..? Just throwing ideas out there...

Comment: The 'mDown' variable is set > 0 only if an object is selected and shiftKey is pressed (mousedown handler). That's why I do care about event propagation if (mDown) only.

Comment: And yes, I use an OrthographicTrackballControls attached to the renderer.domElement. I switch it off (controls.enabled=false) in mousedown if shiftKey , and enabled it in mouseup. Thanks to tell me where I am wrong here !!

Comment: The issue might be assignment order. If you assign your own functions that stop propagation _after_ letting Three assign its own events, that means that your function will be executed _after_. So the issue might be that you initialise controls before you make modification, which means it will execute the event handler Three has added before it gets to your and stops propagation... (aka the order in which event handlers are added is the order in which they execute). Maybe that?

Answer (score 0):

Semicolon is missing on all `e.stopPropagation()` statements.

Comment: Thanks to JS's automatic semi-colon insertion that makes no difference. **This would have been better of as a comment**.